# R - Prop.Table Barplot conditional coloring

Tags: r

I want to change the color of the bar red if it is less than 99% and green if it is greater than or equal to 99%.

I have the ff. table:

```
data <- c(15,320,7,0,19,0)
table <- matrix(data, nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

Creating a barpot:

```
barplot (prop.table(table,2)*100,
     col = ifelse(prop.table(table,2)[1,]>=.99, c("green","gray"),c("red","gray")))
```

In the resulting plot, all bars turned green. But based on the proportions, the middle bar should turn red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can overlay 2 barplots and have the same output:

```
bar.height <- prop.table(table,2)[1,]
bar.base <- c(1,1,1)
barplot(bar.base, border=NA)
barplot(bar.height, col = ifelse(bar.height<=.99, "red", "green"), border = NA, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice solution, haven't thought of that! The only downside – you can only do it to the bottom parts of the bars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `ifelse` statement returns

```
> ifelse(prop.table(table,2)[1,]>=.99, c("green","gray"),c("red","gray"))
[1] "green" "gray"  "green"
```

So, no, I would not expect anything to turn red ;) In general, when confronted with a problem like that, first substitute the problematic expression by manual values. Also, bar plot coloring goes by rows of the matrix. I.e., if given a matrix like

```
table <- matrix(c(20, 30, 40, 15, 10, 5, 30, 10, 10), 
  nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=T)
barplot(table, col=c("DarkGreen", "Ivory", "NavyBlue"))
```

...each bottom part of each bar is now dark green, each middle part is now ivory, and each top part is now navy blue. To get a more sophisticated color scheme you probably will have to code the bar plot manually or use ggplot2 with a manual scale.

[image]

Comment: That's a great insight @January. In the context of your example, how can I change the "DarkGreen" to "red" when its value is greater than 18?

Comment: You can't, that's the problem. You can change it only for the whole row of the matrix. This is how it is defined in the `barplot` function from the graphics package. You can inspect the code in `barplot.default`.

Comment: Thanks @January! I found a work around by overlaying 2 barplots